# Unintended escaping in JSON String

Tags: java, json

I want to create json string like . .

```
{"data":"{"name":"jay"}"}
```

using **org.json.* packages** . .

or using another packages..

**my code is ::**

```
try {       
String strJSONStringer = new JSONStringer().object().key("name").value("jay").endObject().toString();

String record = new JSONStringer().object().key("data") .value(strJSONStringer).endObject().toString();

System.out.println("JSON STRING " + record);

} catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

System.out.println("### ERROR ###  ::  " + e.getMessage());

}
```

The program's output:

```
JSON STRING {"data":"{\"name\":\"jay\"}"}
```

Comment: The value for `data` is actually enclosed in a string, and the innermost double quotes got escaped.

Comment: @JayPatel: are you sure you want {"data": **"** { **"** name":"jay **"** } **"**} and not {"data":{"name":"jay"}}? Those quotes are in a weird location...

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that you do a `toString()` on the name=jay inner object, which turns this from an object into a string. In the second line you basically then say `data=<string from above>` so that the Json library has to encode the `"` in the string by escaping it with `\`.

So you would probably go like this:

```
JSONObject inner = new JSONObject().put("name","jay");
JSONObject outer = new JSONObject().put("data",inner);

String result = outer.toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't build your JSON String in two parts, this causes the second JSONStringer to escape your data.

Simply use the builder to build nested objects:

```
try {
    String record = new JSONStringer()
            .object()
            .key("data")
                .object()
                .key("name").value("jay")
                .endObject()
            .endObject().toString();

    System.out.println("JSON STRING " + record);

} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println("### ERROR ### :: " + e.getMessage());
}
```

This gives me:

```
JSON STRING {"data":{"name":"jay"}}
```